# Error de MySQL Pantalla en blanco

Tags: mysql

Hola amigos soy nuevo en PHP, estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de inicio de sesión, el código que uso ya es algo viejo, no es un sistema crítico por lo cual no hay tanto problema respecto a agujeros de seguridad, sin embargo nunca esta de más ayudar con esto.

No conecta con la base de datos, el código que controla la conexión es este

```
<?php
require("constants.php");

$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die("Cannot select DB");
    
    ?>
```

Me sale el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/path/public_html/includes/connection.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/path/public_html/index.php(11): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/path/public_html/includes/connection.php on line 4

Gracias a todos

Comment: Estás haciendo varias preguntas en una. ¿qué es lo que actualmente tienes y falla? Que no conecta con la BD?

Comment: @JheymanMejia Me sale el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/path/public_html/includes/connection.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/path/public_html/index.php(11): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/path/public_html/includes/connection.php on line 4

Comment: intenta con esto $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solición en la documentación de MySQL.

El código que ya funciona es:

```
<?php
require("constants.php");

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME) or die("Cannot select DB");

    ?>
```

Gracias de cualquier forma por su ayuda.